# Как я могу привязать значение label к переменной в viewModel

Tags: swift, mvvm

У меня есть viewModel, и в ней есть переменная.
Хочу, чтобы когда у меня меня менялось значение переменной, автоматом менялся label в viewController. Как мне это сделать? Без использования RxSwift или Combine.

Comment: При изменении значения переменной используйте label.text = "<новое значение>".  Если это не ответ, дополните вопрос примером, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
class Dynamic<T> {
    typealias Listener = (T) -> ()
  private var listeners: [Listener] = []
  init(_ v: T) {
    value = v
  }
  var value: T {
    didSet {
      for l in listeners { l(value) } }
  }
  func bind(_ l: @escaping Listener) {
    listeners.append(l)
    l(value)
  }
  func addListener(_ l: @escaping Listener) {
    listeners.append(l)
  }
}
    
infix operator >>>
func >>> <T>(left: Dynamic<T>, right: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
  left.bind(right)
}

func >> <T>(left: Dynamic<T>, right: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
  return left.addListener(right)
}
```

viewDidLoad:

```
viewModel.playerPoints >>> { self.label.text = "\($0)" }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]